# Assign Vue-resource to a store

Tags: vue.js, vue-resource

I am trying to store a resource in a store that can be shared between components according to the following documentation:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md#response
http://vuejs.org/guide/application.html#State_Management

```
var App = Vue.extend({});
getcolleges = '/wp-json/wp/v2/schools-api?filter[posts_per_page]=9999';
var schoolFilter = Vue.extend({
    template: '#school-filter-template',
    data: function(){
        return {
            colleges: ''
        }
    },
    ready: function() {
        this.$http.get(getcolleges).then(function(colleges) {
            this.$set('colleges', colleges.data);
        })
    },
});
```

However, when I try to create a store with the resource to use with other components, I get the following error: "The 'Data' option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions."

```
var App = Vue.extend({});
getcolleges = '/wp-json/wp/v2/schools-api?filter[posts_per_page]=9999';
var store = {
    data: function(){
        return {
            colleges: ''
        }
    },
    ready: function() {
        vue.$http.get(getcolleges).then(function(colleges) {
            vue.$set('colleges', colleges.data);
        })
    }
}

var schoolFilter = Vue.extend({
    template: '#school-filter-template',
    data: store 
});
```

Comment: Try `data: store.data`

Comment: That did it. Thank you!